# How can check a place in a page?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, userscripts

I use something like this to click an element on a page by condition:

```
var findElem = function(elems, text) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].textContent == text) {
            return elems[i];
        } else {
            var result = findElem(elems[i].children, text);
            if (result != undefined) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

switch (document.getElementById('my_id').value) {
    case "1":
        findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla1").click();
        break;
    case "2":
        findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla2").click();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I want to add one more condition to this code.

Page I'm working is something like this:

```
<body id="something">

<div id="something2" class="container">
    <div id="header">
        <a class="hmm" href="somelink"></a>
        <a class="aname" target="_blank" href="anotherlink"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="anotherthing" class="anotherthing2">

<div class="differentthing " style="left: 2px; ">
    <div class="asdafad"></div>
</div>
```

I have to look if `differentthing` has no `style`

in short I want to do something like this:

```
switch (document.getElementById('my_id').value) {
    case "1":
        ---if differentthing has no style attrib then---
        findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla1").click();
        break;
```

so if `differentthing` section of page is like this

```
<div class="differentthing ">
```

then do `findElem.click` thing.

if it's `<div class="differentthing " style="left: 2px; ">` then do nothing.

I hope I can describe. How can I do that? And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch (document.getElementById('my_id').value) {
    case "1":
        // getting an array of elements with "differentthing" class
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("differentthing");

        // if there is just one and it does not have "style" attribute
        if (elements.length == 1 && !elements[0].getAttribute("style")){
            // perform some action
            findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla1").click();
        }        
        break;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work correctly on IE, which has a fairly broken version of `getAttribute`: http://jsbin.com/oqukec/2 Fails in IE7 (and presumably earlier), works in IE8 and IE9.

Comment: getElementsByClassName is also not supported in IE - http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I guess this may be irrelevant due to greasemonkey tag - getting it running in IE is a separate issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Want to see if an element has no style?

For starters, use jquery

```
var hasStyle = $(".differentthing").attr("style")
if(hasStyle){/*...do your cool stuff...*/}
```

The attr method sets or returns an attribute of an element. For you it'd be the style attribute.

Comment: Please don't post jQuery answers to non-jQuery questions.

Comment: @T.J. Why? Is this a forum rule or something? I feel like I was simply trying to be helpful, as jquery is helpful.

Comment: Because JavaScript != jQuery. There are lots of other libraries out there, the OP hasn't said they're using any, they're clearly *not* using jQuery, and there are times when it's not appropriate to load something heavyweight (like, for instance, in a greasemonkey script).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this function to get a attribute, in this case style

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
   <p id="title" style="color:red">algo</p>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var prueba = document.getElementById('title').getAttribute('style');
  document.write(prueba);
</script>
</html>
```

For another example:

```
 switch (document.getElementById('my_id').value) {
   case "1":
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('differentthing');
    for(x in elements){
       if(!x.getAttribute('style')){
           //dont have style attribute do something 
       }
    }
    findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla1").click();
    break;
```